# Wikipedia API returns encoded text for foreign language

Tags: java, json, character-encoding, wikipedia-api

I am trying to get some data from a Wikipedia page. I use this URL to get the data:

```
https://el.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=δίας
```

You can open the [URL](https://el.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=%CE%B4%CE%AF%CE%B1%CF%82) with your browser to see how it looks.

My problem is that the data is encoded and I don't know how to decode them from my android app.

What I have tried so far:

```
URLDecoder.decode(articleText, "utf-8");
```

and

```
 byte [] barr = Base64.getDecoder().decode(articleText);
 Print.e("Decoded value is " + new String(barr));
```

and

```
 byte [] barr =  Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(articleText);
 Print.e("Decoded value is " + new String(barr));
```

All failed. The first one didn't change anything.

The second crashes with log:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 5c

The third crashes with log:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits

Please note that I only try to decode the encoded text and not all the JSON text.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's a JSON string. Did you try parsing it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just extract the text I need. Parsing is not the problem, decoding is.

Comment: @Student: any JSON parser worth its salt will decode those Unicode-escapes into proper strings. So don't try to hand-build a parser even if you "just want to extract the text". That's what a paser does! (Also side-rant: JSON isn't just "text in curly braces and quotes", it has an actual spec and using a proper parser handles all those "weird corner cases" for you which, as it turns out, you want to be handled!)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Ok I will give it a try

Comment: @Student those escape sequences are valid in Python too. If you write `print('\u0394\u03af\u03b1\u03c2 \u03a7\u03b1\u03ca\u03b4\u03b1\u03c1\u03af\u03bf\u03c5 - \u03b1\u03b8\u03bb\u03b7\u03c4\u03b9\u03ba\u03cc\u03c2 ')` you'll get `'Δίας Χαϊδαρίου - αθλητικός '`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just a JSON response, even though using escape sequences in a JSON response like this is *un*usual.

You don't need to decode anything. Any character in a JSON string value can be replaced by a Unicode *escape sequence*. Parsing the JSON string will return the actual characters.

Those escape sequences are valid in Python too.

```
print('\u0394\u03af\u03b1\u03c2 \u03a7\u03b1\u03ca\u03b4\u03b1\u03c1\u03af\u03bf\u03c5 - \u03b1\u03b8\u03bb\u03b7\u03c4\u03b9\u03ba\u03cc\u03c2 ')
>>> 'Δίας Χαϊδαρίου - αθλητικός '
```

This:

```
import requests
url="https://el.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=δίας"
source = requests.get(url).json()
print(source)
```

Produces

```
{'batchcomplete': '', 'query': {'normalized': [{'from': 'δίας', 'to': 'Δίας'}], 'pages': {'18786': {'pageid': 18786, 'ns': 0, 'title': 'Δίας', 'extract': 'Το όνομα Δίας μπορεί να αναφέρεται στα παρακάτω:\n\nΜυθολογίαΟ Δίας (μυθολογία) - πατέρας των θεών της ελληνικής μυθολογίας.ΑστρονομίαΟ Δίας (πλανήτης) - ο μεγαλύτερος πλανήτης του ηλιακού συστήματος.\nΔίας LI - φυσικός δορυφόρος του πλανήτη Δία.\nΔίας LII - φυσικός δορυφόρος του πλανήτη Δία.\nΚαυτός Δίας - ονομασία κατηγορίας εξωηλιακών πλανητών.ΤέχνηΔίας του Οτρίκολι - μνημειώδης προτομή του ομωνύμου αρχαίου θεού.\nΔίας και Γανυμήδης - γλυπτό που εκτίθεται στο Αρχαιολογικό Μουσείο Ολυμπίας.\nΔίας και Θέτις - πίνακας του Γάλλου ζωγράφου Ζαν Ωγκύστ Ντομινίκ Ενγκρ.ΑθλητισμόςΑ.Σ. Δίας Πατρών - αθλητικός σύλλογος μπέιζμπολ\nΠ.Σ. Δίας Δίου - ποδοσφαιρικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Κορυδαλλού - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Σαραβαλίου - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΑ.Σ. Δίας Κωστακιών - αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Ηρακλείου - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΠ.Α.Σ. Δίας Αγίου Δημητρίου - πολιτιστικός αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΠ.Α.Σ. Δίας Κασσιώπης - ποδοσφαιρικός αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Ολυμπιακού Χωριού - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΑ.Σ. Δίας Χαϊδαρίου - αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Αχαρνών - αθλητικός όμιλος'}}}}
```

And

```
source['query']['pages']['18786']['extract']
```

Prints

> 'Το όνομα Δίας μπορεί να αναφέρεται στα παρακάτω:\n\nΜυθολογίαΟ Δίας (μυθολογία) - πατέρας των θεών της ελληνικής μυθολογίας.ΑστρονομίαΟ Δίας (πλανήτης) - ο μεγαλύτερος πλανήτης του ηλιακού συστήματος.\nΔίας LI - φυσικός δορυφόρος του πλανήτη Δία.\nΔίας LII - φυσικός δορυφόρος του πλανήτη Δία.\nΚαυτός Δίας - ονομασία κατηγορίας εξωηλιακών πλανητών.ΤέχνηΔίας του Οτρίκολι - μνημειώδης προτομή του ομωνύμου αρχαίου θεού.\nΔίας και Γανυμήδης - γλυπτό που εκτίθεται στο Αρχαιολογικό Μουσείο Ολυμπίας.\nΔίας και Θέτις - πίνακας του Γάλλου ζωγράφου Ζαν Ωγκύστ Ντομινίκ Ενγκρ.ΑθλητισμόςΑ.Σ. Δίας Πατρών - αθλητικός σύλλογος μπέιζμπολ\nΠ.Σ. Δίας Δίου - ποδοσφαιρικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Κορυδαλλού - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Σαραβαλίου - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΑ.Σ. Δίας Κωστακιών - αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Ηρακλείου - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΠ.Α.Σ. Δίας Αγίου Δημητρίου - πολιτιστικός αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΠ.Α.Σ. Δίας Κασσιώπης - ποδοσφαιρικός αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Ολυμπιακού Χωριού - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΑ.Σ. Δίας Χαϊδαρίου - αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Αχαρνών - αθλητικός όμιλος'

Notice that I used the original Greek parameter values in the URL string. Python 3 strings are Unicode, so there's no need to escape non-English text.

**This is unusual**

Using escape sequences for all characters is unusual. The HTTP response contains `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` which clearly says the content is UTF8 characters. There's no need to escape them at all.

```
source = requests.get(url)
print(source.encoding)
>>> 'utf-8'
```

[The API's JSON parameters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats#JSON_parameters) offer a way to receive the text without encoding, by adding the `utf8=true` parameter. [This URL](https://el.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&utf8=true&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=%CE%B4%CE%AF%CE%B1%CF%82) (`https://el.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&utf8=true&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=δίας`) returns the strings unescaped.

Using

```
url="https://el.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&utf8=true&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=δίας"
source = requests.get(url)
print(source.text)
```

Shows that the response *text* is no longer escaped:

> {"batchcomplete":"","query":{"normalized":[{"from":"δίας","to":"Δίας"}],"pages":{"18786":{"pageid":18786,"ns":0,"title":"Δίας","extract":"Το όνομα Δίας μπορεί να αναφέρεται στα παρακάτω:\n\nΜυθολογίαΟ Δίας (μυθολογία) - πατέρας των θεών της ελληνικής μυθολογίας.ΑστρονομίαΟ Δίας (πλανήτης) - ο μεγαλύτερος πλανήτης του ηλιακού συστήματος.\nΔίας LI - φυσικός δορυφόρος του πλανήτη Δία.\nΔίας LII - φυσικός δορυφόρος του πλανήτη Δία.\nΚαυτός Δίας - ονομασία κατηγορίας εξωηλιακών πλανητών.ΤέχνηΔίας του Οτρίκολι - μνημειώδης προτομή του ομωνύμου αρχαίου θεού.\nΔίας και Γανυμήδης - γλυπτό που εκτίθεται στο Αρχαιολογικό Μουσείο Ολυμπίας.\nΔίας και Θέτις - πίνακας του Γάλλου ζωγράφου Ζαν Ωγκύστ Ντομινίκ Ενγκρ.ΑθλητισμόςΑ.Σ. Δίας Πατρών - αθλητικός σύλλογος μπέιζμπολ\nΠ.Σ. Δίας Δίου - ποδοσφαιρικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Κορυδαλλού - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Σαραβαλίου - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΑ.Σ. Δίας Κωστακιών - αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Ηρακλείου - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΠ.Α.Σ. Δίας Αγίου Δημητρίου - πολιτιστικός αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΠ.Α.Σ. Δίας Κασσιώπης - ποδοσφαιρικός αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Ολυμπιακού Χωριού - αθλητικός όμιλος\nΑ.Σ. Δίας Χαϊδαρίου - αθλητικός σύλλογος\nΑ.Ο. Δίας Αχαρνών - αθλητικός όμιλος"}}}}

Comment: Thanks a lot, the utf8=true was what I was searching. Also  using a JSON parser did the trick.